# How to view font of current page in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts

How to know font of the current web page in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways:
1. View source (right click > View Page Source or Ctrl+U) and find the font from the style sheet.
2. Install [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/), find the DOM element, and look at its style.

Answer (score 2):

Recent Firefox versions allow you to right-click on any element and select *Inspect Element*. Then, click the *Style* button at the bottom, and select the *Computed* tab on the top right. Look for `font-family`.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Neither answer applies to current versions of Firefox, so I am posting this answer.

FireBug is not available as a Web Extension, and Firefox devtools have been updated.

Current Firefox versions allow you to right-click on any element and select *Inspect Element*. Then, click the *Inspector* button on the devtools toolbar, and select the *Computed* tab on the top right of the devtools. Look or search for `font-family`.